# julia @parallel for loop - how to update a dictionary (array) and return the results?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I was wondering how can I update an array in a @parallel for loop in a function and return the results. Here is a simple example:

```
addprocs(2)

function parallel_func()
   a = Dict{Int64, Int64}()
   @sync @parallel for i in 1:10
      a[i] = 2*i
   end
   println(length(a))
   return a
end 

a = parallel_func()
println(length(a))
```

Here, `a` is empty after running the for loop with `@parallel` macro. 
I know @parallel copies the data on each worker and does not touch the original data, but I thought there might be a way to fetch the data from all the workers. I appreciate if you can comment on any alternatives to expedite a for loop like the example above.

Answer (score 0):

`@parallel` has a return. You can return an array by reducing with `vcat` or `hcat`:

```
arr = @sync @parallel (vcat) for i in 1:10
  ...
  element
end
```

You can cat to an array of `Pair`s and build a `Dict` from that.

### Edit

I noticed that you're actually looking to mutate an array. In that case you should use a `SharedArray` or a `DistributedArray`.

Comment: Is the `@sync` needed? I think not.
Also I suggest using `pmap` instead.

Comment: Yeah, `pmap` is probably better for this. It'll go faster if the iterations are not equal in time.

Comment: I like it because it is much easier to reason about what it is doing -- being that it is a function, not a macro.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try `pmap` as well!

Comment: Extended chat is not for comments. You should check out the Julia Gitter for followup questions: https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia . That said, to use other fixed arguments just use a closure: `(i) -> parallel_func(i,other_stuff)`

Comment: BTW, how can I pass fixed arguments to a function in `pmap`. For instance, in the above example I think I can remove the for loop and try `function parallel_func(i) = 2*i` and then use `Results = pmap(parallel_func, 1:10)`. What if `parallel_func` has some other fixed arguments e.g. `function parallel_func(i,j,k) ` (I want to apply f on different elements of `i = 1:10`, but other arguments are fixed)?

Comment: Please go to the Gitter channel for extended chat @user3727930. Once again, the answer to your question is a closure.